# Undefiend functions after slider initialization bxslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I have a problem with BxSlider. After initialization I tried to call default methods from BxSlider, but in console I'm getting error "TypeError: mainSlider.reloadSlider is not a function". Also with console.dir I'm not getting default methods from object, just jQuery methods. Any Help?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var singleSlide = $('.bxslider li').length == 1;
    var sliderSpeed = $('.bxslider').data('speed')?$('.bxslider').data('speed'): 5000;
    //bx-slider function
    mainSlider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        auto: !singleSlide,
        touchEnabled: true,
        pause: sliderSpeed,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        onSliderLoad: function(){
            $('.bxslider').css("visibility", "visible");
            resizeHomeSlider();
        }        
    });

    mainSlider.reloadSlider();
}
```

Comment: Is .bxslider an actual DOM element? Can you post the relevant HTML as well?

Comment: Yes, .bxslider element is in layout

Comment: Also, I first load jquery, then bxslider plugin, and then I load my custom.js file.
Edit: Slider is working okay, but I can't do anything with it except initialization

Answer (score 1):

Changes:

- Added var to `mainSlider` to keep it in local scope not global
- [`auto`](http://bxslider.com/options#auto) is a Boolean
- <del>- [`pause`](http://bxslider.com/options#pause) is an Interger</del> (Took a second look, and I see that's ok.)
- Define resizeHomeSlider outside the `bxSlider` scope then callback from within the bxSlider scope.

This is of course untested since not every detail was provided.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var singleSlide = $('.bxslider li').length;
  var sliderSpeed = $('.bxslider').data('speed') ? $('.bxslider').data('speed') : 5000;
  //bx-slider function
  var mainSlider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({ // Include a var so mainSlider is not global 
    auto: true, //------auto is a Boolean (true/false, 0/1...)[it operates on it's own.]
    touchEnabled: true,
    pause: sliderSpeed,
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    onSliderLoad: resizeHomeSlider
  });
  // Define the function outside of bxSlder block
  resizeHomeSlider(idx) {
    // It doesn't matter if you use idx, but you should have it declared.
    $('.bxslider').css("visibility", "visible");
    // Do resizing magic...
  }

  mainSlider.reloadSlider();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

<ul class="bxslider" data-speed='5000'>
  <li></li>
```